# Why browser cannot display url that downloads base64

Tags: html, image, google-api, base64, google-cloud-storage

I have this:

```
url='https://storage.googleapis.com/img.cp.io/avatars/d2d48e49-82be-4cf6-be6e-11ada43c7339'

token='ya29.c.Ko8BxgcTu8....5y7colBQo2bGFC2EM2vD_KK2pZmNd6xIo70g0b_ioulXWlES40P-AEtzRqsNOCZXqCE'

curl "$url?access_token=$token" | pbcopy
```

the above will download base64 and put it on your clipboard (use xclip on linux).

*if I put the copied base64 string into a browser searchbar, the image will display fine.*

the **problem** is if I put the above *url* (*not* the base64 but the url) into the browser searchbar, or an img src tag:

```
<img src="$url?access_token=$token">
```

it should download the base64 and then display the image, but it doesn't work..why won't it download the base64 from the url and display it? why won't the url work directly in a browser searchbar, but instead only work when the base64 is copied to the searchbar?

Comment: note the access token probably expired before you try, it's only good for an hour

Comment: Regardless of the answer, please DO NOT include your access token in HTML results. It is a complete credential to act as the user who received it for ANY purpose. Use signed URLs for this purpose instead.

Comment: Use the Chrome debugger (Press F12). Double-check the `img src` matches what you expect or right-click and select `View page source`.

Comment: Because the browser is retarded sometimes and just can't? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it just can't display it because the browser is dumb:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829286